# Перевести в javascript

Tags: delphi, javascript

Доброго дня.
Помогите реализовать код в javascript.
В Delphi это выглядело бы так...

```
if pos('en', str) > 0 then begin  {код...} end;
```

Comment: Думаю, как-то так:

    if(str.IndexOf('en') != -1) { 
       // your code here
    }
    else {
        // another code
    }

А вообще JavaScript и Delphi в одном вопросе - нечто странное

Comment: Ну как бы на чем знаю, на том и показал... )

Comment: @vipuncle если бы Вы ещё озаботились изучением русского языка, то задавать вопросы было бы проще. Обсолютно!

Comment: На какую галку? Тут куда не жми везде нужны какие-то баллы, насчет русского языка только и можешь заметить??? Лучше дай ответ по вопросу, умник.

Comment: @vipuncle вы грубиян.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( str.indexOf("en") + 1 > 0 ){
   /*код*/  
}
```

Т.е. тут условие: если строка "en" является подстрокой в строке str то выполняется /*код*/
Я делфи не знаю, но думаю что правильно понял код. Поправьте меня если не так.

Comment: интересно, а почему не str.indexOf("en") != -1 ?

Comment: можно и так, на вкус и цвет.

Comment: Обсолютно верно поняли, всем спасибо.

Comment: @DreamChild а я люблю оба числа в квадрат возводить и на тысячу умножать. ММ, это так красиво.

Comment: @lampa действительно, чего процессору зря простаивать, пусть хоть помещение отапливает

Comment: http://jsperf.com/testccc Что мой вариант, что ваш — одинаковы по ресурсозатратам. Петросяны блин.

Comment: @ZondArt потому что умный компилятор преобразует этот код в более совершенный.

Comment: @ZondArt во-первых, это только потому что компилятор способен грамотно оптимизировать и не такое, а  во-вторых, кто вам вообще сказал, что мой первоначальный комментарий относится к производительности? Речь о том, что это менее очевидно (пусть и ненамного, но это скорее симптом -  обычно программисты, предпочитающие такие конструкции, впоследствии рождают и вовсе монструозные вещи). Если вам важна производительность в подобных вещах, то вам нужно писать явно не на JS